# Azure AD multitenancy configuration with .NET Core

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory

I have two applications registered in Azure AD. One for front-end app and one for API(.NET Core). I need these applications to be multitenant. So I have set `Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant)` selection in AzureAD for both applications. I am using Azure AD V2.0 endpoints. I am able to get the `id_token` successfully from front-end app. But when it is passed to API, even though I have set `TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer` to `false`, it tries to validate the issuer and returns 401 Unauthorized status. It seems `TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer` flag is ignored.

I noticed a mismatch when I check the log

`INFO Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.? [?] - MESSAGE: AzureADJwtBearer was not authenticated. Failure message: IDX10205: Issuer validation failed. Issuer: 'https://sts.windows.net/9967b0b6-c5d3-*************/'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidIssuer: 'null' or validationParameters.ValidIssuers: 'https://sts.windows.net/{tenantid}/'.
2020-01-13 14:34:51,884  INFO Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService.? [?] - MESSAGE: Authorization failed`

Please notice here the `Issuer` is `https://sts.windows.net/9967b0b6-c5d3-*************/`

But when I decode the `id_token` I can see the Issuer is set as `"iss":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/9967b0b6-c5d3-*************/v2.0"` which I think the correct end point for AzureAD V2.0. Could this be a reason for the above unauthorized return.

Below is the authentication related code in `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
        .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
        {
            options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";

            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
        });
```

Below is the appSettings.json configuration

```
"AzureAd": {
"Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
"Domain": "my_doamin.com",
"TenantId": "common",
"ClientId": "https://my_doamin.com/api-test"
}
```

The API end point with `Authorize` attribute

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "AzureADBearer")]
[Route("getPotalAdminUsers")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> getPotalAdminUsers()
{
    //Code
}
```

I went through some SO questions regarding this issue. But none helped me. 
I appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and the reason behind the issue I faced. 
I am posting the answer so that anyone who is facing the same issue can get the issue cleared out.

I was using `OpenIdConnect middleware` in Startup.cs which was the reason behind the issue. `OpenIdConnect middleware` is used when we need to sign-ing in the users from our app. But in our context we sign-ing in the users from the front-end app. **API does not sign-ing in users! API just needs to validate the `access_token`**.

To validate `access_tokens` we should use `JwtBearer middleware` instead of `OpenIdConnect middleware`.

So replace the

```
services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
    {
        options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";

        options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
    });
```

With

```
services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";

            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
        });
```

For more information refer the below link

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/wiki/How-ASP.NET-Core-uses-Microsoft.IdentityModel-extensions-for-.NET